# I should see the result once I click the button, but I can't

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a random number generator as a practice.
But once I put this code in my WordPress blog and click the button, I cannot see any result come out. It appears in the making phase. But once post is published, I cannot see the result.
Could you please help what I should do? here is the code you can refer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Number Generator</title>
  <style>
    /* Styles for the title, button, and result text */
    h1 {
      font-size: 32px;
      color: #333;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 40px;
    }

    #result {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    button {
      display: block;
      margin: 20px auto;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    button:hover {
      background-color: #45a049;
    }

    h2 {
      font-size: 24px;
      color: #333;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    h3 {
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #666;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function generateNumbers() {
      var fixedNumbers = [];
      var randomNumbers = [];
      var additionalNumber = 0;

      for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var inputElement = document.getElementById('fixedNumber' + i);
        var fixedNumber = parseInt(inputElement.value);

        if (!isNaN(fixedNumber) && fixedNumber >= 1 && fixedNumber <= 69) {
          fixedNumbers.push(fixedNumber);
        }
      }

      while (randomNumbers.length < (5 - fixedNumbers.length)) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 69) + 1;

        if (!fixedNumbers.includes(randomNumber) && !randomNumbers.includes(randomNumber)) {
          randomNumbers.push(randomNumber);
        }
      }

      additionalNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 1;

      var resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');
      resultDiv.innerHTML = "<h2>Random Numbers: " + fixedNumbers.concat(randomNumbers).join(', ') + "</h2>" +
                            "<h3>additional number: " + additionalNumber + "</h3>";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Number Generator</h1>
  
  <label for="fixedNumber1">Fixed Number 1:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fixedNumber1" min="1" max="69">
  <br>
  <label for="fixedNumber2">Fixed Number 2:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fixedNumber2" min="1" max="69">
  <br>
  <label for="fixedNumber3">Fixed Number 3:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fixedNumber3" min="1" max="69">
  <br>
  <label for="fixedNumber4">Fixed Number 4:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fixedNumber4" min="1" max="69">
  <br>
  <label for="fixedNumber5">Fixed Number 5:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fixedNumber5" min="1" max="69">
  <br>
  <button onclick="generateNumbers()">Generate Numbers</button>
  <div id="result"></div>

  <script>
    // Verify if JavaScript code is running
    console.log("JavaScript code is running...");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `<script>` that's in the `<head>` is parsed before the DOM is completely loaded so any references to the elements within the `<body>` is useless. Read this [article](https://kinsta.com/blog/defer-parsing-of-javascript/).

Comment: @zer00ne The references will not be made until the function defined in the `<script>` is called, which will be when the `<button>` the references it is clicked.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ah, I didn't see the inline event handler.

Answer (score 0):

As your JS codes are perfectly working so it seems like you are not inserting the JS codes in the WordPress site in the right place.

Here is how you can add custom JavaScript codes into your WordPress site:

First way:

If you already have a script.js file connected to your theme then you can edit and insert these JS codes into it.

Second way:

You can also add these JS codes as a separate JS file by copying all these codes into a JS file and naming it `number-generator.js` and then put it into the correct directory.

After that edit `functions.php` and add these codes below:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'you-name-it', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/number-generator.js', array(), _S_VERSION, true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'you-name-it' );
```

at the end but before the php closing tag which is `?>` and save the file.

Comment: I am using a specific plugin, which provides html inserter. It normally works when I put Google map HTML code, for example. All user UI has been properly generated with the code I updated here, except for the result. The result is not printed.

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with inserting custom html using plug-ins in WordPress website. But in that way have you ever inserted JS codes that work?

Comment: I just put this code above on html input menu by using elementor plug-in.

Comment: In this way, you can add html but for adding JS codes you have to follow what I said in my answer.

Comment: second way, correct??

Comment: Both works. If you can follow the first one then it will work too :)